# Why does my app just disconnect after a while? (desktop browsers w/SSE)

Tags: signalr

This seems to happen in most desktop browsers.  Client-side logging captures this kind of activity while the connection is still operational and messages are still being received:

```
[20:26:45 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:26:45 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:26:45 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C23%7C7%2C0%7C8%2C0%7C9%2C0&tid=10'
[20:26:47 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:26:47 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:26:47 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C23%7C7%2C0%7C8%2C0%7C9%2C0&tid=9'
[20:26:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect
[20:26:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0
[20:26:50 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected
```

It can stay operational for quite a while, over 20-30 minutes or longer.  But the trouble starts when EventSource readyState changes from 0 to 2 and it never recovers:

```
[20:34:48 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0
[20:34:48 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting due to the server connection ending
[20:34:50 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:34:50 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:34:50 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=BT%2C3%7CBU%2C0%7CBV%2C0%7CBW%2C0&tid=3'
[20:34:53 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect
[20:34:53 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 2
[20:34:55 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:34:55 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:34:55 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=BT%2C3%7CBU%2C0%7CBV%2C0%7CBW%2C0&tid=7'
[20:34:58 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect
[20:34:58 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 2
[20:35:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:35:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:35:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=BT%2C3%7CBU%2C0%7CBV%2C0%7CBW%2C0&tid=2'
[20:35:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect
[20:35:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 2
[20:35:05 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:35:05 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:35:05 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=BT%2C3%7CBU%2C0%7CBV%2C0%7CBW%2C0&tid=7'
[20:35:08 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect
[20:35:08 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 2
[20:35:10 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:35:10 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:35:10 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=BT%2C3%7CBU%2C0%7CBV%2C0%7CBW%2C0&tid=6'
[20:35:13 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect
[20:35:13 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 2
[20:35:15 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
[20:35:15 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting
[20:35:15 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/signalr?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6m-VvbPcIRx9eRBMBms9uNsT5bQOZPkRZmiyHPGYZJUba52h9ys9n1TYdywkehezJM-N3x6HbOJLWNU9m3pFDb1PDxMDn79O3CLY72O6eI0Cgzb_bzowfvfJw9TKTeYl0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mysitehub%22%7D%5D&messageId=BT%2C3%7CBU%2C0%7CBV%2C0%7CBW%2C0&tid=2'
[20:35:18 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect
[20:35:18 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 2
[20:35:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout (30000ms), disconnecting.
[20:35:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive
[20:35:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
```

This was captured from Firefox, but it happens in Chrome too.  I'm confident that the actual web application, hosted on Arvixe, is not "going dark" for 30000ms or more to cause this.  How does one start to troubleshoot something like this?

Comment: When you say messages are still being received. What do you mean? Are those received messages showing up in the trace?

Comment: I meant to indicate the topmost section of log entries while the system is still working fine - IOW, I'm trying to compare "what normal looks like" with "what it looks like after SignalR messages are no longer received anymore" . . . I am assuming that since readyState is always 0 while it's working right, and readyState is always 2 after it stops working, that might point to the problem but I don't know enough about what readyState really means to deduce from these logs what the root cause really is.